# extract date Datepicker Android

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker, android-dialogfragment

I've been trying to extract the date that I get with the `Datepicker` as it says [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)  The problem comes when I try to use a function that I've created (getDate), I can't call the method from the `activity` in order to obtain the string, because these method can't be resolved. Can anyone explain me why?

This is the code for the `Datepicker` that I have in my activity.

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    private String date;
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
         date=Integer.toString(year)+"-"+Integer.toString(month)+"-"+Integer.toString(day);
    }

    public String getDate(){
        return date;
    }
}


public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
   String date = newFragment.getDate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a possible solution on this post [Android - Date Picker - Obatin Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140306/android-date-picker-obatin-value) ,specially this comment:

```
declare Textview as public & static & call it on dateSet method by-className.textviewName.setText();
```

But I still don't understand the reason why I can't do what I initially wanted

Comment: DialogFragment doesn't have getDate method, but DatePickerFragment has that method.

Comment: the method getDate is the one I implemented and I was trying to call so neither DatePicker nor DialogFragment have that method.

Comment: Ohh i forgot that. I think now you know why getDate is not accessible.  ;-)